# RecyclerView - разная разметка

Tags: android, recyclerview

Смотрел, я смотрел в сторону `RecyclerView` и наконец решил кинуть `ListView` и на тебе!

В "плохом прошлом" мой `ListView` использовался для двух разметок. Сейчас я повторил это, но что-то упустил. Суть в следующем: разметки две, одна для правого сообщения (своего), другая для левого сообщения (чужого). Так вот, левые сообщения как и было размещены верно. Правые же "переехали" и теперь все слева. А веды правые должны быть справа! Причём, сообщения у меня оформлены по-разному и все выглядит как положено, но все слева!

Вот мой код адаптера. Первый код для `RecyclerView` :)

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainActivity.RVAdapter.AdapterHolder> {

    public class AdapterHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tv_full_author, tv_circle_author, tv_client, tv_text, tv_data;

        AdapterHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv_full_author = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.full_nick);
            tv_circle_author = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.first_char_nick);
            tv_client = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.reply_marker);
            tv_text = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.message);
            tv_data = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
    }
}
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> adapterList;
    int type;

    RVAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dat){
        adapterList = dat;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public AdapterHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(((i==0)? R.layout.item_right: R.layout.item_left), null);
        AdapterHolder pvh = new AdapterHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AdapterHolder holder, int i) {
        HashMap<String,String> fast_parse = adapterList.get(i);
        String author_str = fast_parse.get("author");
        String client_str = fast_parse.get("client");
        String text_str = fast_parse.get("text");
        String data_str = fast_parse.get("data");
        holder.tv_full_author.setText(author_str);
        holder.tv_circle_author.setText(author_str.substring(0,1));
        if(!client_str.equals("0"))
        {
            holder.tv_client.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.tv_client.setText(client_str+",");

            if(client_str.equals(nick)&&(getItemViewType(i)==1))
            {
                holder.tv_client.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#A40dff"));
            }
            else{
                holder.tv_client.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
        else{
            holder.tv_client.setText("");
            holder.tv_client.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        holder.tv_text.setText(text_str);
        holder.tv_data.setText(data_str);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        if (adapterList.get(position).get("author").equals(nick))
        return 0;
        else
        return 1;
            }

        public int getItemViewTypeCount(){
            return 2;
        }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return adapterList.size();
    }
}
```

Есть подозрения, что в `onCreateViewHolder()` я как то неправильно создаю `view`, хотя и учитываю `getItemViewType()`

Comment: По первому вопросу можете почитать [тут](http://panavtec.me/retain-restore-recycler-view-scroll-position).

Comment: На первый взгляд все вроде правильно. Смущает строка создания View. Должно быть что то вроде: `View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(((i==0)? R.layout.item_right: R.layout.item_left), viewGroup, false);`. Я бы вообще такие конструкции не использовал, а разделил на несколько строк с более внятной логикой инициализации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для реализации двух разных типов элементов списка нужно:

- два `ViewHolder`'а
- переопределить метод `getItemViewType`
- переопределить метод `onCreateViewHolder`
- добавить `switch` в `onBindViewHolder` для того что бы различать разные `ViewHolder`

**Реализация:**

- создаем `ViewHolder`'ы

  ```
  public class ViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

      private TextView label1, label2;

      public ViewHolder1(View v) {
          super(v);
          label1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
          label2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text2);
      }
  }

  public class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

      private ImageView ivExample;

      public ViewHolder2(View v) {
          super(v);
          ivExample = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivExample);
       }
   }
  ```
- Переопределяем метод `getItemViewType`:

  ```
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (items.get(position) instanceof User) {
            return USER;
        } else if (items.get(position) instanceof String) {
            return IMAGE;
        }
        return -1;
    }
  ```
- переопределяем метод `onCreateViewHolder`:

  ```
  @Override
  public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());

    switch (viewType) {
        case USER:
            View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_viewholder1, viewGroup, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder1(v1);
            break;
        case IMAGE:
            View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_viewholder2, viewGroup, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder2(v2);
            break;
        default:
            View v = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, viewGroup, false);
            viewHolder = new RecyclerViewSimpleTextViewHolder(v);
            break;
    }
    return viewHolder;
   }
  ```
- определяем какой тип элемента списка к нам попал:

  ```
  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
        case USER:
            ViewHolder1 vh1 = (ViewHolder1) viewHolder;
            configureViewHolder1(vh1, position);
            break;
        case IMAGE:
            ViewHolder2 vh2 = (ViewHolder2) viewHolder;
            configureViewHolder2(vh2, position);
            break;
        default:
            RecyclerViewSimpleTextViewHolder vh = (RecyclerViewSimpleTextViewHolder) viewHolder;
            configureDefaultViewHolder(vh, position);
            break;
    }
  }
  ```

Попробуйте добавить себе такую реализацию, должно все получиться!

Comment: Спасибо, я уже сам справился, дело было в том, что я создавал `view` не так, как нужно)